# JCR 2.0 How to implement a tag based document repository

Tags: jackrabbit

I am completely new to this and have a question similar to
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315031/best-way-to-implements-a-tag-based-search-system-by-jcr-like-modeshape/) but more basic. After reading the JCR 2.0 spec, I came up with the following node structure.

[image: nodes]

hoping to provide both tag searching and management, like option 2 in the referenced post. Is this even on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question, I was overwhelmed by the last updates to Jackrabbit. They did however point me to MongoDB, wherupon I realized that MongoDB was the solution that I was looking for.